# Issue migrating Rails 3.2 :includes call to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database, rails-activerecord

I'm upgrading a Rails application from v3.2.13 to v4.1.5. Consider the following models.

```
class Camera::Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :camera                    

  def self.cleanup(opts)
    # blah blah method stuff
    system_clips = Camera::Clip.includes(:camera).where(['cameras.control_system_id = ?', opts[:control_system_id]])
    # In Rails 4, raises Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'cameras.control_system_id' 
  end
end

class Camera < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :control_system 
  has_many :clips, dependent: :destroy
  # rest of class
end
```

I can get the method to function as it had originally by changing the `:includes` call to `:joins`, but why is that necessary? I thought `:includes` used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` call on the database to combine the resources?

Answer (score 0):

This may have been lost on me in Release Notes documentation, but a second step is needed to tell the where clause what I mean by `'cameras'`.

[This documentation](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods:references) pointed me to the `:references` method.

Swapping out the line for

```
Camera::Clip.includes(:camera).where('cameras.control_system_id = 13').references(:camera)
```

shows the exact same output in the Rails console as my environment running in Rails 3.2.13, with no error! Great success.